# Use uniqid for upload file system

Tags: php, file

I want to know if I use `uniqid` function for file upload system,
I mean that every file that someone upload I change is name to `uniqid` name

So its can happen that two files will be the same name?
if yes what is the solution for that?
should I do:

```
$uniq = uniqid();
while (file_exists($uniq)) $uniq = uniqid();
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: That looks like a decent solution *for normal numbers of files*. It depends on the scope of your system; having a massive amount of very small files uploaded will increase the risk of hitting multiple duplicates, which will impact performance but little else. You have 16^13 possible values (13 hexadecimal chars), which is a whopping 4.5e15 unique IDs. If you factor in Nyquist rates, you should expect to have only half that, or about 2,250,000,000,000,000 files at the very most, before you hit frequent looping and start to see problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So its can happen that two files will be the same name?

Yes. [`uniqid()` is nothing more than a timestamp](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/09/php-convert-uniqid-to-timestamp/). Therefore, if two files were uploaded at the same time they could have the same filename.

> If yes what is the solution for that?

There are many solutions. Basically they all boil down to adding some kind of unique string. For example, you could use: `md5($filename . time())` (which might still have collisions) or better yet: `md5($filename . $database_insert_id)`.

Comment: md5 its 32 chars no? What about uniqid() + $insert_id ?

Comment: Yes, `md5()` generates a 32 character string. Yes, you could use `uniqid()` + `$insert_id`. Frankly, you could use just insert id. In the end, all you're trying to do is ensure uniqueness. You database id should be *unique*.

Answer (score 0):

`uniqid()` is based on the specific microtime, so it is pretty safe to say it is very hard to get dublicate filenames when using it. At the same time that is based on system time and it is possible to get two people uploading files at the exact same time (although very unlikely) so you can just append also the username to the filename, so it is virtually impossible for any of the files to have dublicated names.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the uniqueness of your string passing a prefix and increasing the entropy. Try doing something like this:

```
$prefix = {the original file name} + {the file size};
$fileName = uniqid($prefix, TRUE);
```

Doing something like this you take advantage of two different factors: the client file name and the size. Both combined can highly increase the uniqueness of the returned string. For more details about the prefix and the entropy parameters please refer to the official php documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php